# Cannot connect to MySQl database from Eclipse DataSource Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jdbc

http://motionsharing.com/site/download/acefad55f1e81e456d71a7448b278915

Cannot connect to MySQl database from Eclipse DataSource Explorer.

I tune appropriate driver but I cannot to connect.
P.S.: I can connect to derby db and I can connect to mysql db but only from code, but I want to connect to mysql db from Data Source Explorer to get posivbilities to create tables and so on.

What is wrong ?

I can connect through code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver loading success!");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
        String name = "root";
        String password = "root";
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, password);
            System.out.println("Connected.");
            con.close();
            System.out.println("Disconnected.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [download](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) MySQL JDBC driver and add it to the settings.

You will see these screens when you try to create a new connection profile in Datasource Explorer. In the last step, you'll have to point to the right downloaded JAR file.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: but what is then com.mysql.jdbc.Driver?

Comment: It is a library to connect to MySQL database. If you download from the link I posted, you'll find it.

Answer (score 2):

In Driver Properties make sure to use:

```
URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema_name

Database: schema_name
```

So Eclipse will show the tables en the Data Source Explorer.

Comment: without **schema_name** appending in the end of URL,table node won't expand,though it can still display tables node but cannot be expanded, great answer!